# How to update the layers in Geonode with cascading WMS from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wms, geonode

We began a project in my office in which we would like to have all our geographical data in a central repository where we can search them, insert and edit metadata and view them on a map, so our choice is Geonode.

We have a lot of data around on different machines and servers and on different physical locations so we dont necessarily want to put them on a single drive and / or convert them into PostGIS layers. So what we were thinking was to have a couple geoserver instances locally on the different offices and then have geonode consume WMS services from these geoservers.

So what we did was to create cascading WNS on the geoserver instance that runs Geonode.
The problem is that we cannot get Geonode to read those new WMS services. We tried to run **geonode updatelayers**. The script runs without any error but only updates the existing shapefile layers and not the cascading WMS. When we run

```
 geonode updatelayers -s Ktimanet2
```

and the name of the store it gives an error:

```
 FailedRequestError: No store found named: Ktimanet2
```

This is what my layers look like in Geoserver:
[image]
Any ideas anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer. If anyone is interested it can be found here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/geonode-users/HiCQ-aM4Ak8

In short: gsconfig 0.6.7 was too old, needed to update to a more recent version.